# Highest Value among 3 Numbers

Tags: java, data-structures

**PROBLEM STATEMENT** : SRV college wants to recognize the department which has succeeded in getting the maximum number of placements for this academic year. The departments that have participated in the recruitment drive are CSE,ECE, MECH. Help the college find the department getting maximum placements. Check for all the possible output given in the sample snapshot

**Note : If any input is negative, the output should be "Input is invalid".  If all department has equal number of placements, the output should be "None of the department has got the highest placement".**

Sample Input 1:

```
Enter the no of students placed in CSE:90
Enter the no of students placed in ECE:45
Enter the no of students placed in MECH:70
Sample Output 1:
Highest placement
CSE
```

Sample Input 2:

```
Enter the no of students placed in CSE:55
Enter the no of students placed in ECE:85
Enter the no of students placed in MECH:85
Sample Output 2:
Highest placement
ECE
MECH
```

Sample Input 3:

```
Enter the no of students placed in CSE:0
Enter the no of students placed in ECE:0
Enter the no of students placed in MECH:0
Sample Output 3:
None of the department has got the highest placement
```

Sample Input 4:

```
Enter the no of students placed in CSE:10
Enter the no of students placed in ECE:-50
Enter the no of students placed in MECH:40
Sample Output 3:
Input is Invalid
```

I was able to come up with a code which basically passes all the visible condition, but failing to test one. Not really sure where I am going wrong.

I totally agree the below code isn't the efficient

```
import java.util.*;
class Placement{
public static void main(String[] args) {
int x,y ,z ;
scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in) ;
System.out.printIn( "Enter the no of students placed in CSE: " );
x=sc.nextInt( );
System.out.printIn("Enter the no of students placed in ECE:" );
y=sc.nextInt( ) ;
System.out.println("Enter the no of students placed in MECH:" );
z=sc.nextInt( ) ;
if(x==z && x==y && y==z){   
System.out.printIn("None of the department has got the highest placement" ) ;
}
else if(x<0 || y<0 || z<0){
System.out.printIn("Input is Invalid" ) ;
}
else{
System.out.println( "Highest placement" );
if(x>=z && x>=z){
if(x==y){
System.out.printIn( "CSE" );
System.out.printIn("ISE" );
}
else if(x==z) {
System.out.printIn("CSE" ) ;
System.out.printIn( "MECH" ) ;
}
else{
System.out.println("CSE" );
}
}
else if(y>=z){
{
if(y==z){
System.out.printIn( "ECE" );
System.out.printIn( "MECH" ) ;
}
else{
System.out.println("ECE" ) ;
}
else{
System.out.printIn( "MECH" ) ;
}
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Proposed grade: 85. 71 / 100
Result Description
Failed tests
Test 2: CheckConditionsForTwoMax
Test 1: Check Conditions

Summary of tests
*Note: All the test cases might not have same weightage
7 tests run/ 6 tests passed
```

Comment: Please include all code and output in the question itself

Comment: problem is the platform I am coding doesn't let me to copy or paste the code

Comment: @Cruncher I have added the code by taking image out. FYR

Comment: Sorry that I left the question unclear by adding image of my code, I was able to extract the text from the image and added the code snippet along with obtained output.

Comment: The code you posted will not compile: it has `System.out.printIn` (before last char is a capital `i` instead of a lower case `L`). You also have 2 `else` blocks after a single `if` statement.

Comment: @BartKiers Thank you for your suggestions. I had some mistakes when I extracted text from the image. Thas the reason for that incorrect syntax and mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Well figured out the mistake, not the efficient answer but got it working.

```
import java.util.*;
class Placement{
public static void main(String[ ] args){
int a, b, c;
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System. in) ;
System.out.println("Enter the no of students placed in CSE:");
a=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the no of students placed in ECE:");
b=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the no of students placed in MECH:");
c=sc.nextInt();
if (a>b && a>c){
System.out.println("Highest placement" ) ;
System.out.println("CSE");
}
else if(a<0 || b<0 || c<0){
System.out.println("Input is Invalid");
}
else if(b>a && b>c){
System.out.println("Highest placement") ;
System.out.println("ECE") ;
}
else if(c>a && c>b){
System.out.println("Highest placement") ;
System.out.println( "MECH" ) ;
}
else if(a==b && b==c && c==a){
System.out.println( "None of the department has got the highest placement" ) ;
}
else if(a==b){
System.out.println("Highest placement");
System.out.println("CSE");
System.out.println("ECE");
}
else if(a==c){
System.out.println("Highest placement");
System.out.println("CSE") ;
System.out.println("MECH") ;
}
else{
System.out.println("Highest placement");
System.out.println("ECE") ;
System.out.println("MECH") ;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake was you have typed ICE instead of ECE in a==b condition

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 public class Placement{
     public static void main (String[] args) {
         int ece,cse,mech;
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the no of students placed in CSE:");
         cse=sc.nextInt();
                 
         System.out.println("Enter the no of students placed in ECE:");
         ece=sc.nextInt();
                
         System.out.println("Enter the no of students placed in MECH:");
         mech=sc.nextInt();
         sc.close();
                
         if(ece==cse&&ece==mech)
             System.out.println("None of the departments has got the highest placement");
         else if (ece<0||cse<0||mech<0)
             System.out.println("Input is Invalid");
         else
         {
             System.out.println("Highest placement");
             if((cse>=ece)&&(cse>=mech))
                 if(cse==ece)
                      System.out.println("CSE"+"\nECE");
                 else if (cse==mech)
                     System.out.println("CSE\n"+"MECH");
                 else
                     System.out.println("CSE");
             else if (ece>=mech&&ece>=cse)
                 if(ece==mech)
                     System.out.println("ECE\n"+"MECH");
                 else if(ece==cse)
                     System.out.println("ECE\n"+"CSE");
                 else
                     System.out.println("ECE");
             else
                     System.out.println("MECH");
         }
     }
 }
```

*Assessment report
[-]Failed tests
Test 4: Check No-Highest-Placement
Test 6: Check No-Highest-Placement
[-]Test 1: Check Conditions

[-]Summary of tests
*Note: All the test cases might not have same weightage

|  7 tests run/ 5 tests passed |

*

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class Placement
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the no of students placed in CSE:");
        int cse = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the no of students placed in ECE:");
        int ece = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the no of students placed in MECH:");
        int mech = sc.nextInt();
        
        if(cse < 0 || ece < 0 || mech < 0) 
            System.out.print("Input is Invalid");
        else if(cse == ece && ece == mech) 
            System.out.print("None of the department has got the highest placement");
        else if (cse == ece && cse > mech)
            System.out.print("Highest placement\n CSE\n ECE");
        else if (ece == mech && cse < ece)
            System.out.print("Highest placement\n ECE\n MECH");
        else if (cse == mech && ece < mech)
            System.out.print("Highest placement\n MECH\n CSE");
        else if (cse > ece && cse > mech)
            System.out.print("Highest placement\n CSE");
        else if (ece > cse && ece > mech)
            System.out.print("Highest placement\n ECE");
        else if (mech > cse && mech > ece)
            System.out.print("Highest placement\n MECH");
    }
}
```

This will work perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

The code need to check if the number of placement is in zeroes

```
import java.util.*;
public class Placement {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Enter the no of students placed in CSE:");
    String str1 = sc.nextLine();
    int i1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
    System.out.printf("Enter the no of students placed in ECE:");
    String str2 = sc.nextLine();
    int i2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
    System.out.printf("Enter the no of students placed in MECH:");
    String str3 = sc.nextLine();
    int i3 = Integer.parseInt(str3);
    if (i1 == 0 && i2 == 0 && i3 == 0) {
        System.out.println("None of the department has got the highest placement");
    } else if (i1 == i2 && i2 == i3 && i3 == i2) {
        System.out.println("None of the department has got the highest placement");
    } else if (i1 < 0 || i2 < 0 || i3 < 0) {
        System.out.println("Input is Invalid");
    } else if (i1 == i2 && i1 != 0) {
        System.out.println("Highest placement");
        System.out.println("CSE");
        System.out.println("ECE");
    } else if (i1 == i3 && i1 != 0) {
        System.out.println("Highest placement");
        System.out.println("CSE");
        System.out.println("MECH");
    } else if (i2 == i3 && i2 != 0) {
        System.out.println("Highest placement");
        System.out.println("ECE");
        System.out.println("MECH");
    } else if (i1 > i2) {
        if (i1 > i3) {
            System.out.println("Highest placement");
            System.out.println("CSE");
        } else if (i1 == i3) {
            System.out.println("Highest placement");
            System.out.println("CSE");
            System.out.println("MECH");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Highest placement");
            System.out.println("MECH");
        }
    } else if (i2 > i1) {
        if (i2 > i3) {
            System.out.println("Highest placement");
            System.out.println("ECE");
        } else if (i2 == i3) {
            System.out.println("Highest placement");
            System.out.println("ECE");
            System.out.println("MECH");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Highest placement");
            System.out.println("MECH");
        }
    } else if (i1 != 0 && i2 != 0 && i3 != 0 && i1 == i2 && i2 == i3) {
        System.out.println("Highest placement");
        System.out.println("CSE");
        System.out.println("ECE");
        System.out.println("MECH");
    } else {
        System.out.println("MECH");
    }

}
```